# Limit of $f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, &x \text{ is irrational} \\ \frac{1}{q}, &x=\frac{p}{q}\text{ in lowest terms}\end{cases} \quad$ on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

My book has previously investigated the limit of the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, &x \text{ is irrational} \\ \frac{1}{q}, &x=\frac{p}{q}\text{ in lowest terms}\end{cases}$$ across the interval $[0,1]$. In particular, the book shows that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x)=0$ for any $a \in [0,1]$. I want to extend this claim to any $a \in \mathbb R$. Any suggestions to improve how I have laid out the argument would be appreciated.

---

**Lemma**

> Every number $w \in \mathbb R$ can be written as some $z \in \mathbb Z$ plus some $r \in \mathbb R$ with $r \in [0,1)$ using the following formula: $w = \lfloor w \rfloor + (w-\lfloor w \rfloor)$. $z = \lfloor w \rfloor$ and $r=w-\lfloor w \rfloor$.

In order to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to w}f(x)=0$ for any $w \in \mathbb R$, we must prove the following statement: for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, there is a $\delta \gt 0$ such that for any $x \in (w-\delta, w+\delta) \setminus \{w\}$, we have $|f(x)| \lt \varepsilon$.

Consider any $w \in \mathbb R$ and an arbitrary $\varepsilon \gt 0$. By the *Archimedean Property*, we know that there is an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{n} \lt \varepsilon$. For this given $n$, we see that there are finitely many $n'_i$ such that $\frac{1}{n'_i} \gt \frac{1}{n}$, where $n'_i=n-(n-i)$ for any $ i \lt n$ and $i \in \mathbb N$.

Initially stipulate that $\delta \lt \frac{1}{2}$. This will ensure that the interval $(w-\delta,w +\delta)$ falls between two integers $z_0$ and $z_2$ where $z_2 - z_0 =2$. Next, consider any $x \in (w-\delta, w+ \delta) \setminus \{w\}$. If $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$, then $f(x)=0 \lt \frac{1}{n} \lt \varepsilon$. The remaining $x$ belong to two mutually exclusive categories:

1. $x \in \mathbb Q$ **and** $f(x) \leq \frac{1}{n} $
2. $x \in \mathbb Q$ **and** $f(x) \gt \frac{1}{n} $

If $x$ is a member of the first category, then we are fine because $\frac{1}{n} \lt \varepsilon$. So let $x$ be a member of the second category, meaning that $x$ must map to one of the $n'_i$ satisfying $\frac{1}{n'_i} \gt \frac{1}{n}$. Further, because $x \in (w-\delta, w+ \delta) \setminus \{w\}$, we know that $x \in (z_0,z_2)$. Let $z_1$ be the integer satisfying $z_0 \lt z_1 \lt z_2$. Applying our lemma, we have that $x$ must equal one of the following values: $ z_0 + (x-z_0)$ or $z_1 + (x-z_1)$. Without loss of generality, suppose the former.

Noting that $x \in \mathbb Q$, we must have that $x = \frac{p}{n'_i}$ for some $p \in \mathbb Z$, in lowest terms. We also have that $\frac{p}{n'_i}=x=z_0 +(x - z_0) \in \mathbb Q$, which implies that $x-z_0 \in \mathbb Q$ and can be written as $x-z_0=\frac{p-z_0\cdot n'_i}{n'_i}$. If $p$ and $n'_i$ are coprime, so, too, must $p-z_0\cdot n'_i$ and $n'_i$. This shows that $f(x)=f(x-z_0)$.

From our lemma, we know that $ \frac{p-z_0\cdot n'_i}{n'_i} \in [0,1)$. This means that $p-z_0\cdot n'_i$ can only take on finitely many values: $1,2, \cdots, n'_i-1$. In particular, then, $x$ can only take on finitely many values, all which will satisfy $f(x) \gt \frac{1}{n}$. Returning to our variable $w$, consider the finite set $D_w = \{|x-w| : f(x) \gt \frac{1}{n} \}$: this set is a collection of the distances from $w$ to the $x$'s belonging to the second category. Let $d_{min} \in D_w$ denote the smallest such distance. Set $\delta \lt d_{min}$. This procedure can be repeated for any of the finitely many $n'_i$. Once the procedure has been carried out for all $n'_i$, we will have a $\delta$ that satisfies our desired criteria.

Comment: This is a lot of work if you know it for $[0,1].$ It is easier to just show that $f(x+1)=f(x).$ Then there is only a slight bit of work to prove what you want when $a\in\mathbb Z,$ but the other cases just fall out.

Comment: The standard proof works for all $a$ at once. I do not see how the restriction $a\in[0,1]$ makes any difference.

Comment: @markvs where might I find the "standard" proof? My book (Spivak's *Calculus*) has an argument that, as written, can only be applied to $[0,1]$. Thomas Andrews' point about $f(x+1)=f(x)$ would need to be added to the argument.

Comment: @S.Cramer:  I have not and hopefully will not read Spivak. I studied this in the first semester analysis course when I was a freshman, long ago in a  faraway land. The proof did not have cases $a<1, a\ge 1$ or any cases at all.